# Replace String and check for uniqueness within String

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to replace specific string with empty value with in string. But below snippet is not removing spaces. Also is there easy approach to look for uniqueness with in strings separated my delimiter?

```
 String str = "||MGR||RAI MGR||PRE RAI MGR||PRE RAI SPR||PRE SPR||";
 String newStr = str.replaceAll("RAI", "");
 System.out.println("Updates String is::"+newStr);
```

Output I am looking for is ||MGR||PRE MGR||PRE SPR||

Thanks

Comment: Since Strings are immutable in Java, you might want to consider storing the elements to be filtered in some Collection and modify the content of your Collection, rather than modifying a String using this type of approach?

Comment: `"RAI"` doesn't look like a regular expression to me. If you don't know what that is, then you should be using `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`. It still replaces all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

--- Edit Update ---

Wait a second, you are doing a number of things here.  You're not just doing string replacements, you are also compacting the fields between the `||` delimiters such that you don't have duplicate fields with the same content.

If you were just stripping the "RAI" then you would have

```
||MGR||MGR||PRE MGR||PRE SPR||PRE SPR||
```

So, first, split all your fields into Strings, along the `||` delimiter.  Then strip each string of the undesired "RAI".  Add them to a `Set<String>`, and then rebuild the input string from the items in the `Set`.

--- original post follows ---

You will get a section with two spaces using the technique you are driving at, that's because "PRE RAI MGR" will compact down to "PRE  MGR".

One trick is to replace "RAI " with " ", then replace " RAI" with " " and finally replace "RAI" with ""

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("RAI ", "").replaceAll(" RAI", "").replaceAll("RAI", "");
```

Comment: The first replacement will concatenate two non-"RAI" values into one.  Might want to fix it.  Actually, all of these techniques will strip spaces in the wrong way

Comment: So there is no regex that can fix the problem without doing 3 replaceAll? Something like `\s?RAI\s?` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Include a space in your `replaceAll()` regex, then using Java 8, you can remove duplicates.  Otherwise, you'd have to manually remove duplicate yourself which is still possible, but why reinvent the wheel (except for learning purposes).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "||MGR||RAI MGR||PRE RAI MGR||PRE RAI SPR||PRE SPR||";
    // "RAI\\s?" means there may be a single space after "RAI"
    String newStr = str.replaceAll("RAI\\s?", "");
    System.out.println("Updates String is:: " + newStr);
    // Remove duplicates
    System.out.println("Duplicates Removed:: " + Arrays.stream(
            newStr.split("(?=\\|\\|)"))
                .distinct()
                .map(s -> (s))
                .collect(Collectors.joining()));
}
```

Results:

```
Updates String is:: ||MGR||MGR||PRE MGR||PRE SPR||PRE SPR||
Duplicates Removed:: ||MGR||PRE MGR||PRE SPR||
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` method of String takes a regex so you could pass one and use this instead

`String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\s?RAI\\s?", "");`

[Edit]
You only need to remove the trailing space so get the desired output. Use

`String newStr = str.replaceAll("RAI\\s?", "");`

Complete code:

```
String str = "||MGR||RAI MGR||PRE RAI MGR||PRE RAI SPR||PRE SPR||";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("RAI\\s?", "");
Set<String> parts = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(newStr.split("||")));
StringBuilder sdb = new StringBuilder("||");
for (String part : parts) {
    sdb.append(part).append("||");
}
newStr = sdb.toString();
System.out.println("Updates String is::" + newStr);
```

Comment: This may be upvoted, but it isn't going to ensure the uniqueness of each run between the `||` delimiters.

Comment: This regex is removing RAI. But how can I remove duplicates once new string is formed. Can I use pattern instead of collections?

Comment: You cannot replace them all with a regex.  This requires more computational power than a discrete finite automata.  You cannot solve the de-duplication with a string replace (easily) because you would have to not "replaceAll(...)" (with respect to the de-duplication) but rather "replaceAllAfterTheFirst(...)".  In short, it's far better to actually split the string and then rebuild it, using a Set to "keep a list" containing only unique values.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I agree with you. Added code to do de-duplication and preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String wordToReplace = "RAI";
String regex = "\\s*\\" + wordToReplace + "\\b\\s*";
str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

Comment: You should probably escape wordToReplace with "Pattern.quote"

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` the string to omit " RAI" or "RAI", `split` to check the uniqueness of values and `create` new string with unique values.

```
String str = "||MGR||RAI MGR||PRE RAI MGR||PRE RAI SPR||PRE SPR";
String newStr = "||";
str = str.replaceAll("( |)RAI", "");
String[] values = str.split("\\|\\|");

//add only unique values to new string
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
  if(!newStr.contains(values[i].trim())){
    newStr += values[i].trim() + "||"; 
  }
}
System.out.println("Updates String is::" + newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs. Based on comments and suggestions I managed to get desired output using below code

```
    String str = "||MGR||RAI MGR||PRE RAI MGR||PRE RAI SPR||PRE SPR||";
    String noDupBRole = "||";

    String newStr = str.replaceAll("RAI ", "").replaceAll(" RAI", "").replaceAll("RAI", "");
    System.out.println("New String is::"+newStr);
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(newStr.split(Pattern.quote("||"))));

    for(String st : set) {
        if(st.isEmpty()) continue;
        noDupBRole += st+"||";
    }

    System.out.println("No Duplicate ::"+noDupBRole);
```